# Barssince the highest bar in the last X bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do I find the number of bars that have passed since the highest point in the last X bars.

Let's say X = 10. This doesn't work:

```
float h = ta.highest(high, 10) 
float d = ta.barssince(high == h)
```

Because in this case the code would measure the distance to the last candle which was the highest to the previous 10 candles (not to the current candle), see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case use

```
d = ta.highestbars(10)
```

or `d = math.abs(ta.highestbars(10))` to get positive values[image]

Comment: Lovely. Exacly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

use without var

```
h = ta.highest(high, 10) 
d = ta.barssince(high == h)
```

it will work correctly
or use following code

```
d = ta.barssince(ta.pivothigh(10, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, var was a bug, it shouldn't be there - fixed now. But even without var it doesn't work. I would expect that it would work, but it doesn't. Because in this case the code would find the distance to the bar which was the highest at the previous 10 candles before the bar.

Comment: Also, it will not work with pivothigh as there could be no pivot. Imagine if the price was going down 5 days and then up 5 days. There is no pivot high in this case. However the price 10 days ago still might be higher than the current price.

Comment: Added an image to the original question explaining why the normal barssince wouldn't work in this case.